# How to open pages inside the same DIV

Tags: html, href, target

I´ve got a main page with a `menu` (with links to my sub-sites) and a `div` (where my sub-sites will appear). This is my home.asp

Then I have a folder 'sub-site1' with 2 pages (A.asp and B.asp) that have links between them.

When I click 'sub-site1' at the menu, the A.asp page appears in my div. But if I click in the B link (inside A.asp) the B.asp will open in a blank page.

**link to A.asp** (in home.asp):

```
<a href="sub-site1/A.asp" target="div_id">sub-site1</a>
```

**link to B.asp** (in A.asp):

```
<a href="B.asp" target="div_id">B</a>
```

also try with

```
<a href="sub-site1/B.asp" target="div_id">B</a>
```

Could anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very normal because your B link is in A.asp and the A.asp doesn't contain a frame whose name is div_id. You can try to put the B link in home.asp or use the jQuery .load function as Pete said.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="clickThis" href="javascript:void(0);" target="div_id">B</a>
```

use jquery.load now

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickThis").click(function(){
      $("#div_id").load("B.jsp");//this will load B.jsp inside div_id
      //**in case you want to pass parameters to B.jsp**
      $("#div_id").load("B.jsp",function(){
       param1:value,
       param2:value2
});

    });
    });
```